# How can I get value from a MemberSelectExpressionTree

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am implementing a rule where I want to check the value of `leftOperand` & `rightOperand` of a `BinaryExpressionTree` whether they are empty.

If the `leftOperand` & `rightOperand` is a string literal, I can get the value out of the `LiteralTree` but if the `leftOperand` & `rightOperand` is a member select I can't get the value out of it. Need help on that.

for example:

if the line is `if(sampleString != "stringValue")`, I can get the value, But if the line is `if(sampleString != StringUtils.EMPTY)` or `if(sampleString == FINAL_VARIABLE_WITH_SOME_VALUE)` I can't really get the value out of it.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to implement a rule _for_ Java?

Comment: Indeed @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam